Tratando de añadir texto a imagen a imagen usando canvas, pero no funciona
estoy intentando convertir una imagen a un canvas, y luego agregarle un texto a la imagen y convertirla nuevamente en una imagen, pero estoy teniendo problemas para hacerlo, el texto NUNCA se añade a la imagen final.
Al final de la función subo la imagen al servidor, pero la imagen subida no tiene el texto, solo la imagen.
He intentado de muchas maneras diferentes y el resultado es el mismo, ¿alguien puede decirme qué estoy haciendo mal por favor?
GRACIAS de antemano...
async function saveConfiguration() {
    try {
      const {
        left: caseLeft,
        top: caseTop,
        width,
        height,
      } = phoneCaseRef.current!.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      const { left: containerLeft, top: containerTop } =
        containerRef.current!.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      const leftOffset = caseLeft - containerLeft;
      const topOffset = caseTop - containerTop;
  
      const actualX = renderedPosition.x - leftOffset;
      const actualY = renderedPosition.y - topOffset;
  
      //create canvas
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
      const userImage = new Image();
      userImage.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      userImage.src = imageUrl;
      await new Promise((resolve) => (userImage.onload = resolve));
  
      //add image
      ctx?.drawImage(
        userImage,
        actualX,
        actualY,
        renderedDimension.width,
        renderedDimension.height
      );
  
  
      // add text
      ctx.font = `${fontSizeCustom}px Arial`;
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.5)";
      ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // 
      ctx.fillText(customText, fontPosition.x, fontPosition.y);
  
  
  
      const base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
      const base64Data = base64.split(",")[1];
  
      //function convert base64 to blob
      const blob = base64ToBlob(base64Data, "image/png");
      const file = new File([blob], "filename.png", { type: "image/png" });
  
      //upload iamge to server UPLOADTHINGS
      await startUpload([file], { configId });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error al subir imagen");
    }
  }
  


He intentado de muchas maneras diferentes solo veo un codigo de ejemplo... cuales son esas muchas maneras ... cual es el error que arroja el sistema al agregar el texto??? no veo un correcto uso de promise ... se supone que debes anidar el promise y no usarlo consecutivamente ...
